# MySQL - Complicated SUMs inside Query

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

This is going to be tough to explain.

I'm looping through my client records from `tbl_customers` several times a day.

```
SELECT c.* FROM tbl_customers c
```

I'm returning simply the customer's: `customerid`, `name`, `phone`, `email`

Now the weird part.
I want to append 3 more columns, after email:  totalpaid, totalowed, totalbalance
BUT, Those column names don't exist anywhere.

Here is how I query each one: (as a single query)

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS totalpaid 
FROM tbl_customers_bills 
WHERE customerid = X
AND billtype = 1

SELECT SUM(total) AS totalowed 
FROM tbl_customers_bills 
WHERE customerid = X
AND billtype = 2

SELECT SUM(total) AS totalbalance 
FROM tbl_customers_bills 
WHERE customerid = X
AND billtype IN(1,2)
```

So, the `billtype` is the column that tells me whether the record is paid or not.

I am at a loss here.
How can I SUM 3 separate queries into the first query's loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just join customers to bills and do the sums. To separate out totalpaid and totalowed you can use `SUM(CASE` or `SUM(IF` as [wless1's answer demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248418/119477)

```
SELECT c.*,
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalpaid ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalowed ,
        SUM(total) AS totalbalance
FROM 
    tbl_customers c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills  b
    ON c.customerid = b.customerid
     and billtype in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
     c.customerid
```

Because this is MySQL you only need to group on the PK of customer.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a combination of `GROUP`, `SUM`, and `IF`

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, 
SUM(IF(b.billtype = 1, b.total, 0)) AS totalpaid,
SUM(IF(b.billtype = 2, b.total, 0)) AS totalowed,
SUM(IF(b.billtype = 1 OR b.billtype = 2, b.total, 0)) AS totalbalance,
FROM tbl_customers c LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills b ON b.customerid = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html