# MySQL - Complicated CASE/WHEN Condition possible?

Tags: mysql, case, conditional-statements, ifnull

This question is related to my previous post: [MySQL - Complicated SUMs inside Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248349/mysql-complicated-sums-inside-query)

The query is working great, summing up the totals as desired.
I notice that it also ignores any records with NULL values.

Current query:

```
SELECT c.*,
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalpaid ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalowed ,
        SUM(total) AS totalbalance
FROM 
    tbl_customers c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills  b
    ON c.customerid = = b.customerid
     and billtype in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
     c.customerid
```

And it returns **10** customer records beautifully.
As I check the database, I can see **11** customer records, and the eleventh has no correlating records inside the `tbl_customers_bills` table.

I'd like to still return all eleven, even if there are non-existing records in the `tbl_customers_bills` table.  (but with zeros, of course)

I'm stuck with how complicated such a condition can get.
Here's what I've tried:  (to no avail)

```
SELECT c.*,

     (CASE WHEN (total IS NULL) THEN totalpaid = 0

       ELSE
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalpaid ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) totalowed ,
        SUM(total) AS totalbalance
      END)

FROM 
    tbl_customers c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills  b
    ON c.customerid = = b.customerid
     and billtype in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
     c.customerid
```

Comment: Is there a `WHERE` condition you are not telling us?

Comment: And which table does `billtype` belongs to?

Comment: And why do you have `= =` and not just `=` ?

Comment: @ypercube - I would assume it belongs to `tbl_customers_bills` but I don't understand why you think a `where` clause is missing.

Comment: Yes it does but I believe OP just want to replace the NULL's for the 11th row with 0's. But as I mentioned in my answer, "I might very well be totally of" <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might very well be totally of but I believe you are just missing `COALESCE`

```
SELECT c.*,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END), 0) totalpaid ,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END), 0 totalowed ,
       COALESCE(SUM(total), 0) AS totalbalance
FROM 
    tbl_customers c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills  b
    ON c.customerid = = b.customerid
     and billtype in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
     c.customerid
```

From the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> COALESCE(value,...)
>
> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.
>
> mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
>           -> 1
>   mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
>           -> NULL

Answer (score 1):

How about doing ifnull

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 1 THEN IFNULL(total,0) ELSE 0 END) totalpaid ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN billtype = 2 THEN IFNULL(total,0) ELSE 0 END) totalowed ,
    SUM(total) AS totalbalance
FROM 
    tbl_customers c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers_bills  b
    ON c.customerid = = b.customerid
     and billtype in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
     c.customerid
```